# TEXT column cant have a default value

Tags: sql

```
ALTER TABLE users 
ADD COLUMN house LONGTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '{"owns":false,"furniture":[],"houseId":0}';
```

```
ALTER TABLE users 
ADD COLUMN bought_furniture LONGTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
```

Those 2 are giving me an error while trying to import them. But, when i was in my PC database it didn't give that error.

Comment: What database are you using? Often the dialect of SQL and even the version will make a difference for things like this.

Comment: I assume this is MySQL/MariaDB. Use `varchar`

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?